# What does $C[0,1]$ mean?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, notation

In the context of real analysis, I have found this question:

For each $$f \in C[0,1] $$ there is a series of even polynomials , which converge uniformly on $[0,1]$ to f.

---

What is $C[0,1]$ ? Is it the space of functions which are continuous for $0\le x \le 1 $ ?

Comment: I think it's the space on continuous functions on $[0,1]$.

Comment: A Google search yielded no results?

Comment: Google search with math symbols in 2011 could easily yield no results.  Google is better now...

Comment: @GEdgar If $f \in C^2([a,b])$ does this mean that mean that $f: [a,b]\times[a,b] \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and similarly for $f \in  C^n([a,b])$

Comment: @B2K ... No, the continuous functions $f: [a,b]\times[a,b] \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ would be $C([a,b]^2)$.  I guess $C^2([a,b])$ consists of functions $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ that are twice continuously differentiable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes it is.  It is the space of all continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$.  It has some mathematical structures under some specified operations. For example, $C[0,1]$ is a vector space over the field of reals.

In the space $C[0,1]$, points are just continuous functions.  You can define operation on them like $(f+g)(x) =f(x)+g(x)$  and multiplication like $(fg)(x)=f(x)g(x)=(fg)(x)$. These are called pointwise addition and pointwise multiplication.

Answer (score 3):

$C[0,1]$ is the set of continuous functions on the closed interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: :):):):):):):):)