# What does this notation about ranges mean?

Tags: functional-analysis, notation

This might be a very basic question but I ran into this notation in a numerical methods book

> Let $$g ∈ C[a, b]$$ be such that $$g(x) ∈ [a, b], \forall x \in [a, b]$$

What does the $$C[a, b]$$ mean?

Comment: The set of all the continuous functions in the interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: Though it is generally indexed by the order of derivation and with parenthesis, like in $C^k([a,b])$ for $k-$times derivable and $f^{(k)}$ is continuous function on $[a,b]$. Here it would be $C^0$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of the $c$ in $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3217920/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-c-in-c-c-infty-mathbbr)

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377663/what-does-the-notation-c-mathbbr-mean

Comment: And this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284957/what-does-c0-1-mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of all the continuous functions in the interval $[,]$.